# How to loop through row for new data and then paste into new column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through a dynamic row from the last known value to new values, then add these new values as a column header starting in row 3.

I can paste the new values into the next blank column.

How do I offset to the next empty cell rather than pasting all new values into the same cell?

```vb
Sub Testnewname()

Dim Nw2 As Integer

Dim c As Long
Dim D As Long

Dim Lcol1 As Long
Dim Lrow2 As Long

'' Find last column available in row 3
Lcol1 = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

''Find last row where new info is put via a table defined by
' names =UNIQUE(Table1[[#Data],[Company]],FALSE,FALSE)
Lrow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

''value of the old number of cells used to start from in loop 
Nw2 = Sheets("Cost Table").Range("$H$10").Value

c = Lcol1 + 1 ''allocate a varable to last column + 1

For D = Nw2 To Lrow2   ''for d (i) from cell 19 to last cell

    Cells(D, 10).Copy 'copy cell value

    ''this is where is would of thought pasteinto last column whichit does.
    '  What seems to happen is id doesnt move to next column when it reloops
    Cells(3, c).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
''would of expected that
' when it goes onto next loop that the C (Lcol+1) would recalculate
Next D

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cost Table").Range("H11").Copy

' takes the value from a CountA function in H11 and pastes into H10
'  to update the last place a cell value was prior to running macro
'  and updates Nw2 for running the macro again
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cost Table").Range("H10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False  

End Sub
```

I tried to add a second loop for the column but this does nothing.

```vb
For C = Lcol to Lcol + 1
    For D = Nw2 To Lrow2
        Cells(D, 10).Copy
        Cells(3, c).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next D
Next C
```

Comment: Try adding `c = c + 1` just before `Next D`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this without using a loop, or copy/paste:

```vb
Sub Testnewname()

    Dim Nw2 As Long, ws As Worksheet, wsCostTbl As Worksheet, cDest As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or some other specific sheet
    Set wsCostTbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cost Table")
    'next empty cell on row 3
    Set cDest = ws.Cells(3, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
    'starting row# for copy
    Nw2 = Sheets("Cost Table").Range("$H$10").Value
    
    'using the source range...
    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(Nw2, 10), ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp))
        '...transfer the values, flipping rows and columns using Transpose
        cDest.Resize(.Columns.Count, .Rows.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Value)
    End With
    
    wsCostTbl.Range("H10").Value = wsCostTbl.Range("H11").Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi thank you both for that,  I have tested both ways and work for the life of me couldn't work out the possion of the C=C+1.

Tim i really like this with out looping i did try something like this as i have another script that i removed looping from as itwas so much quiker.

```
With ws.Range(ws.Cells(Nw2, 10), ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp))
        '...transfer the values, flipping rows and columns using Transpose
        cDest.Resize(.Columns.Count, .Rows.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Value)
    End With
```

Is a new one for me and will be very useful in anumber of toold i am createing thank you for this